# Where to enter an IP address on a newly created Hyper-V machine after connected to a network adapter

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Where to enter static IP address on a Hyper-V machine.  I have created a new VM on a hyper-v host, connected to a network adapter, have an IP address available to assign to it, but don't know where to enter the IP address.  The Host already has a static IP address.  Please help!

Answer (score 3):

As TomTom stated in his answer, you assign ip addressing information to a Hyper-V guest just as you would with a physical machine. Connect to the Hyper-V guest from Hyper-V Manager or the SCVMM Admin Console, access the properties of the NIC, and configure the ip addressing information.

Answer (score 1):

A Hyper-V client is like a separate installer. You log into the virtual machine and set up the network there like you would on a normal computer.

You can not enter it on the host because hosts do not deal with clients network stacks - they expose network CARDS - hardware that has a MAC address and that is it.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine behaves exactly like a physical machine, so the right place to configure its networking is *inside the virtual machine itself*, in its network settings; the exact place depends on the O.S. the virtual machine is running.

If the virtual machine doesn't recognize its virtual network adapter, you need to install the Virtual Machine Additions in it, which provide drivers for the virtual hardware emulated by Hyper-V.